# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/ConfigurationProvider

Tags: struts2

lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/ConfigurationProvider exception in tryint to start a sample web application.

However the xwork2.1.3.jar is there in the lib directory I have checked it.

Anybody knows why I might be getting this error.

Comment: Have you tried with xwork 2.2.3? http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts231-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Could you post what is in your /WEB-INF directory?

Answer (score 0):

when you posting a question,please make sure to provide complete information like your struts config file, error console details and any other relevant information..
it will always help  community to provide you best information and suggestion.For your problem my best bet is to download sample applications from strust2 official site and check them out if they are working or not and in case they are working start playing/customize them as per your requirements, it will also help you to check what exactly the structure they have followed which jars they have used and any other standard configurations needed for the web-application

[Example Applications:](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts231-SNAPSHOT)